# What means the part between the date and the server answer in Apache’s log?

Tags: apache-log-files

I have in the log file a following line:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;[05/Aug/2016:00:00:48 +0200];GET /extensions/css/example.css?rev=example HTTP/1.1;200;66931;http://www.example.com/page.html
```

Please explain me, what means the part between the date and the server answer? I'm a bit perplexed about it - it isn't a redirect URL, but what is it then?

**Edit**:
I come to decision, that i've completely misformulated my question - sorry for that.

I don't mean with my question, what are the senses of certain url parts, like `rev=example` etc. I'm rather interesting, why are in the log entry two kinds of url: one of them, the first, beginning with GET, and the second at the entry's end.

I thought firstly its a kind of redirect - but no, the answer code is 200. So what mean two urls / paths in this log entry?

Comment: I am confused so please forgive me. Are you talking about *GET /extensions/css/example.css?rev=example*?? If not, can you cut and paste the snippet from your example into the question? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first URL should be the file that is access, while the second one is the referrer, aka the file/page that made the browser access the first URL.

You can configure what shows up in your log files. Typically by modifying the  'LogFormat' lines in your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
More information about what information you can show: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about `GET /extensions/css/example.css?rev=example`

The log is telling you that on the page `http://www.example.com/page.html` a GET request was made of `/extensions/css/example.css` with the key being `rev` and the data being `example`

If you aren't familiar with querystrings, the URL is passing data to the file it is requesting. Assuming there is some code to parse the data something will happen if `rev=example`.  Something different might happen if `rev=production` (for instance).

You can also POST data to a page to modify the result, in this case it doesn't appear in the URL and usually done via a form.